# create threads by yourself

Tags: c, posix

I have been asked to write a system call that creates threads within context of the calling thread that is they share the same virtual space. The function header should be:

```
thread_create( void*(*start_func)() ,void* stack, unit stack_size );
```

I don't know how I should use the stack as specified in the header for the second thread. I'm sure it has something to do with the virtual memory sharing requirement of the function.

Please give me a clear and obvious explanation of this as I am very new. I am using the POSIX API.

Comment: As this is as a system call, it probably depends on the OS you are running in.

Comment: @JohmDon Isn't posix created to be portable across different systems? I would expect it to be possible to do only with posix calls. Otherwise it does not make much sense to mention it.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is POSIX system call to create a thread, you should look into phtread implementations for different platforms. Linux uses the [clone](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) system call with the `CLONE_THREAD` flag for example

Comment: "using the POSIX API" and "writing a system call" are mutually incompatible -- system calls are implemented in the kernel and are below the POSIX API.  You could implement a function using the POSIX API, but then it wouldn't be a system call.

Answer (score 2):

While threads may share many things, the one thing they cannot share is their stack space.  Generally speaking (not to any specific OS implementation), you might malloc() some memory that the new thread will use as it's stack, and then let the new thread know how much memory it has been allocated for its stack using the stack_size parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To implement this with the POSIX API, see the `pthread_attr_setstack` and `pthread_create` API calls.  This would be implementing it on top of the POSIX API, not as a system call.